# Trouble while feeding Output of dense layer to lstm cell

Tags: tensorflow, input, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I want to feed the output tensor  of a hidden layer of shape (1,70,70) to an lstm Layer. The lstm layer has 70 units and 1 time step. How can I reshape the tensor to be compatible with the input of lstm in tensor flow.
    input_layer = layer.dense(self.xs, 70, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='random_uniform')

```
    hidden1 = layer.dense(input_layer, 70, activation='relu', 
kernel_initializer='random_uniform')
    hidden2 = layer.dense(hidden1, 70, activation='relu', 
kernel_initializer='random_uniform')
    hidden3 = layer.dense(hidden2, 70, activation='relu', 
kernel_initializer='random_uniform')
    hidden4 = layer.dense(hidden3, 70, activation='relu', 
kernel_initializer='random_uniform')

    lstm_cell_1 = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(self.num_units, forget_bias=1.0, state_is_tuple=True)
    lstm_cell_2 = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(self.num_units, forget_bias=1.0, state_is_tuple=True)
    lstm_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell([lstm_cell_1, lstm_cell_2], state_is_tuple=True)
    initial_state = lstm_cell.zero_state(self.batch_size, dtype=tf.float32)
    with tf.variable_scope('lstm1'):
        outputs, final_state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(lstm_cell, hidden4, initial_state=initial_state)
```

Comment: Please provide a code sample of what you have so far. Are you using Keras or some other layer library?

Comment: Any reason why you're not using Keras. Not to point anything wrong with the code, but the code would've been cleaner if you used Keras.

Comment: it is because of the flexibilty of tensor flow that I am using it. Anyways,I have sorted out the problem. the problem was due to the shape of the input.